# How to stop my UIButton animation SWIFT

Tags: swift, animation, button

I made an animation with UIButton via somes images.
Here's the code:

```
         @IBAction func Touchdown(sender: AnyObject) {
    Izer.setImage(image1, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    Izer.imageView!.animationImages = [image1, image2, image3, image4,                    image5,
        image6, image7,image8]
    Izer.imageView!.animationDuration = 0.9
    Izer.imageView!.startAnimating()
            playButton.enabled = false



}





@IBAction func TouchUp(sender: AnyObject) {

    soundRecorder.stop()
    playButton.enabled = true


}
```

When I touch the button , the animation start. But I want to stop it via my Touchup function.

How can I do it ?

Thank you , and sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: Have you tried putting `Izer.imageView!.stopAnimating()` in your `TouchUp` method?

Comment: @Phoen1xUK Owwww man thank you !!!

Comment: Just going to add this as an answer so we can close the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `TouchUp` func:

```
Izer.imageView!.stopAnimating()
```

p.s. A good place to find information about functions is in the Apple documentation - it really is quite good. So [this is the page for an imageView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/) and if you look on the left under **tasks**, or if you scroll down, you can see the functions and properties you can call and set for animating an imageView.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like you want the button to act as a toggle switch. On the first touch the button starts animating an imageview and records something. When touched again the animation stops and the button is enabled again.

You can achieve this by declaring a bool variable that tracks the state of the button. If the boolean value is set to true, you run the animation & recording. If the boolean value is false, you stop the and recording.

Here is the sample code :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!
var isButtonPressed = false{
    // Adding a Property Observer, that reacts to changes in button state
    didSet{
        if isButtonPressed{
            // Run the Recording function & Animation Function.
            startAnimationAndRecording()
        }else{
            // Stop the Recoding function & Animation Function.
            stopAnimationAndRecording()
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func changeButtonValue(sender: UIButton) {
    // Toggle the button value.
    isButtonPressed = !isButtonPressed
}

func startAnimationAndRecording(){
    // Add your animation and recording code here.
}

func stopAnimationAndRecording(){
    //Add your stop Animation & Stop Recording code here.
}
```

}

Comment: Hey thank you for the infos ! But I don't know what code to put To stop the animation...